# Create fabric canvas with ngFor in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs, ngfor

I'm using fabric.js with Angular 4. I managed to create a canvas inside a component and successfully draw on it.

I used  `this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1',{});` the `this.canvas.add(New fabric.Rect...)` in my file.ts

Then i tried to generate more than one canvas, i used the *ngFor on my canvas element and managed to get the id attribute to be canvas1, canvas2...

Now the same code `this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1',{}); ...` a is no longer working as if there were no canvas with id = canvas1. When i inspect the dom, the element is right there.

The *ngFor breaks this or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the drawing code was executed before the view is ready, before ngFor is executed.

**The solution is to execute the code after the view is ready using the `ngAfterViewInit()`**